# Do larvae feel pain?

Tags: animal-suffering

Some fruits, like organic guayabas or mangos, are very likely to have "worms" inside. However, they are not exactly "worms", but larvae of flies. I'm not sure whether I would be causing harm by eating the fruit, so I would like to know whether larvae feel pain?

Related questions:

- [Do bivalves such as oysters feel pain or fear?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/q/606/115)
- [Would vegans eat fruits with worms?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/31/do-bivalves-such-as-oysters-feel-pain-or-fear).

Comment: This is a classic [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you mean to ask if eating or disposing of these larva is consistent with a vegan ethical stance — don't be coy — by all means... ask that. But if you truly want to ask about the perception of pain in fly larva, this is not a biology or entomology site; this would be off topic here.

Comment: @RobertCartaino this was my first intention, but I was told by Zanna to rephrase the question. check http://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/posts/606/revisions . what sould I do? sometimes SE model is not 100percent clear to me..

Comment: Hmm my problem with your original question there was that I thought it was too broad (it was two different questions imho) but I don't think this question is off-topic... I think it is answerable and of interest to vegans. Maybe I was wrong in the first place and should not have interfered with your question. But voting to reopen this one...

Comment: @Zanna maybe some edit is needed to make more explicit the connection with veg*s lives